# Problema al llamar metodos en el menu

Tags: java, menú, método

Hola me gustaría saber si alguien puede aclararme como llamar mètodos en los menús de java. Mi duda es la siguiente(adjunto programa para el ejemplo):

```
public void imprimir() {
        Nodo reco=raiz;
        System.out.println("Listado de todos los elementos de la pila.");
        while (reco!=null) {
            System.out.print(reco.info+"-");
            reco=reco.sig;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void vacia() {
        if(raiz==null) {
            System.out.println("La pila esta vacia");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Todavia caben mas valores en la pila, sigue insertando");
        }
    }
    public void cantidad(){
        Nodo reco=raiz;
        int contador=0;
        if(reco!=null) {
            contador++;
            reco=reco.sig;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Hay "+contador+" nodos.");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1-Insertar  2-Extraer   3-Imprimir");
    int op;
    System.out.println("Declara la opcion que desea tomar :");
    op=entrada.nextInt();
    do {
        switch(op) {
        case 1:int x;System.out.println("Declara el numero a insertar");x=entrada.nextInt();insertar(x);break;
        case 2:extraer;break;
        case 3:imprimir();break;
        }
    }while(op!=1||op!=2||op!=3);

    }

 }
```

Mi duda esta en el switch case, a la hora de crear los casos no entiendo porque aveces tenemos que poner entre paréntesis variables y a veces no, y en algunos casos me sale error cuando pongo la variable que creo que es como en este caso. Si alguien puede explicarme como funciona se lo agradecería.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un error en concreto con tu switch sería bueno que compartieses con la comunidad cual es para que alguien pueda echarte una mano para poder solucionarlo.

En cuanto a los switch, la estructura de un switch en Java:

```
int number = 0;
switch (number) {
        case 1:  System.out.println("El valor del numero es 1");
                 break;
        case 2:  System.out.println("El valor del numero es 2");
                 break;
        default: System.out.println("El valor del numero no es 1 ni 2.");
                 break;
    }
```

Los switch comparan el valor de la variable que está entre los paréntesis (en este caso `number`) con los distintos casos que se especifican.
En caso de que la variable no coincida con ninguno de los casos el programa usaría la opción de default.

Este switch sería lo mismo que:

```
if (number == 1) {
    System.out.println("El valor del numero es 1.");
}
else if (number == 2) {
    System.out.println("El valor del numero es 2.");
} else {
    System.out.println("El valor del numero no es 1 ni 2.");
}
```

No se si así te podría quedar un poco más claro. Te dejo también la documentación de Switch en Java para que le puedas echar un vistazo: [Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Para llamar a un método desde un switch sería igual que hacerlo desde fuera de él.

Nombre del método (Variables que necesite);

Los métodos pueden necesitar variables o no, dependiendo de como lo hayas declarado. Vamos a usar de ejemplo el primer método que has compartido:

```
public void imprimir() {
    Nodo reco=raiz;
    System.out.println("Listado de todos los elementos de la pila.");
    while (reco!=null) {
        System.out.print(reco.info+"-");
        reco=reco.sig;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Este método `imprimir()` no necesita variables, si fuese por ejemplo `imprimir(int numero)` tendrías que pasar una variable de tipo int al llamar al método, en este simplemente con llamar al método sería suficiente, por ejemplo:

```
case 1:
    imprimir();
    break;
```

Para el caso `imprimir(int numero)` sería algo tipo:

```
case 1:
  int variable_numero = 0;
  imprimir(variable_numero);
  break;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero mi problema no esta en como formular el switch sino en como llamar a los métodos en el los cases. El problema es que en mi curso me han dicho que cuando llamas a un metodo en un switch case tienes que poner "case 1: (nombre del metodo) (variable que utiliza el metodo);break;" En mi caso no entiendo "(variable que utiliza el método)" ya que si miras en el código que he pasado el método imprimir no recibe ningún valor, ya que es void, así que en dicho caso no entiendo que tendría que poner el el case que deseo llamar al método imprimir.

Comment: Hola @winnie, he actualizado la respuesta ya que no había entendido bien lo que estabas preguntando, disculpa, espero que ahora si este respondiendo a tu duda. Por otro lado, que un método sea de tipo void no significa que no reciba ningun valor, si no que no los devuelve. Si algo no se entiende házmelo saber e intentaré explicarlo de otro modo. Un saludo.